# GCP Kube-Lego forwarding rule pricing

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I've started to use kube-lego to manage load-balancing through a nginx controller, instead of GCP Load Balancer controller.

I am being charged for: `Network Load Balancing: Forwarding Rule Minimum Service Charge in EMEA` right now, at about 21$ per month.

Isn't the load balancing supposed to be done by nginx?
I have TCP Load Balancer in my GCP network resources.

Isn't possible to send the traffic to a node port and do the load balancing on the nginx controller instead ?

I thought the advantage of having a Nginx load balancer would avoid creating a load balancer on GCP and thus avoiding paying crazy expansive network resources.

What is the purpose of the nginx controller then? Beside maybe automatic certificate renewal with LE.

Comment: What does this have to do with Kube-Lego?  That's purely for managing cert acquisition.

Comment: Maybe I simply misunderstood the concept at first. Kube-lego is offering certificate management for kubernetes cluster in two ways: Nginx Ingress Controller and GCE Loadbalancers. In the second one, you pay for Google to do the load balancing for you. Which I tought was not the case in the first one. I am kind of surprise of the need to build a TCP LB. Is there a way to avoid those fees ?

Comment: You most likely have a Service that has `type: LoadBalancer` or an Ingress that is not handled by the nginx-ingress-controller (lacks the annotation `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`).

Check all the Service and Ingress objects and you will find what created the GCE LoadBalancer.